# ClassList Remove seems not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have implemented this animated tabs in my app, following [this setup](https://codepen.io/Gillispeare/pen/bLWREr) on codepen.
Now, instead of jquery I wanted use vanilla Javascript, this is what I wrote:

```
<div class="slides">
              <div class="slides__slide">
                <span class="slide-title">
                  <a href="#">yoga coaching</a>
                  <i class="ion-chevron-down"></i>
                </span>
                  <div class="experience__content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi rem ab voluptate provident voluptatum
                    veniam cupiditate beatae expedita veritatis aliquid officia doloribus dolore maiores doloremque mollitia! A ducimus autem ut!
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus obcaecati velit autem tenetur doloribus perferendis esse odit
                    animi quasi deserunt recusandae perspiciatis a sapiente aliquam qui libero dolor officiis assumenda.
                  </div>
                </div>
```

this is the javascript:

```
const slideTitles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide-title'));
let activeClasses = []
slideTitles.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(activeClasses.length>0){
      activeClasses[0].classList.remove('active')
      activeClasses[0].firstElementChild.getElementsByTagName('i')[0].classList.replace('ion-chevron-up','ion-chevron-down')
      //activeClasses[0].firstElementChild.lastElementChild.classList.replace('ion-chevron-up','ion-chevron-down')
      activeClasses = []
    }
    this.parentElement.classList.add('active')
    this.lastElementChild.classList.replace('ion-chevron-down','ion-chevron-up')
    activeClasses.push(this.parentElement)
  })
})
```

This implementation works well in chrome, firefox opera (I cannot test it on Safari at the moment) but in Edge I have some problem: first of all, when a slide is clicked, the width is incremented first, and then the position (with no transition effect apparently), this happens also in the codepen, but in my implementetion also the remove classList function seems not works: because if i click to another card, the one that is previously selected remains in an active position, and does not go up.

The classList implementation seems work in Edge, and also the code I wrote works in another browser..

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Nope, in console everything ok

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is with `replace()`. When stepping through my own (problematic) code, MS Edge shows `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'`. On the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) it shows `replace` as `?` with a tooltip of `Compatibility unknown; please update this.`.